# wildfly 8.1.0 hot deploy of static content

Tags: deployment, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am working on some JavaScript files, replace the file in tmp/vfs folder. It works fine only two or three times.during work on static content (HTML and JS files) I found, that wildfly seems to stop reloading the changed files after 2 or 3 changes.

I am working on a larger project, it takes 10 min for redeployment.

but I have found some possible solution :

1. hot deployment is fixed in 8.2 . ( but I have some restriction to update the server)
2. bypass redeployment. [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/872052#872052) (I tried this method, but issue is remained)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use exploded deployment and some configuration to enable hot-deployment for static resources, instead of replace the file in tmp/vfs folder. see my blog entry for detail: http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/exploded-deployment-for-wildfly-on

Comment: Thanks @Kohei Nozaki for your great support , can i get some clarification. so is it redeploy every static file changes ? but redeployment is too expensive in my case. by the way I am using eclipse.

Comment: No, redeploy doesn't happen with it. sorry I'm not sure how it will work with Eclipse.